# Exception on Membership.GetAllUsers() after login: "Item has already been added"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have two sites running which share a membership provider. One of them is a ASP Playground site and the other is a site that have the ASP Playground Site Integration Package installed. Let's call them ASPPG site and SIP site.

I sometimes get an error when I run Membership.GetAllUsers() on the SIP site.
This method is overruled by the SIP, so it is not the standard ASP.NET version.

It only occurs sometimes. I have noticed that it only occurs when there is some sort of change to one of the members. Then it must recreate the hashtable that all the users are stored in when calling Membership.GetAllUsers() and it is like this recreation goes wrong somehow.

In the exception that I have pasted below "administratoren" is the username of the login that has had some info changed.

It does not help to force the website to unload by updating the web.config.
It does not help to restart the IIS or completely reboot the server.
After the exception shows up, it keeps on showing up everytime Membership.GetAllUsers() is called. Suddenly, out of the blue, the exception disappears and it is again possible to log in and run Membership.GetAllUsers() without any exceptions.
It pretty much looks like the error is in the database and a way to fix the error is by loading any page of the ASPPG site. Then the error gets fixed on the SIP site.

What causes the exception and how do I stop it?

The complete exception is this:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'administratoren'  Key being added: 'administratoren'
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'administratoren'  Key being added: 'administratoren'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Linje 116:     MembershipUserCollection allUsers;
>   Linje 117:     lock (objLock) {
>   Linje 118:         allUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers();
>   Linje 119:     }
>   Linje 120:
>
> Source File: [WebsiteLocation]\App_Code\MemberInfo.cs    Line: 118
>
> Stack Trace: (Please not that the line numbers of MemberInfo.cs in this stacktrace can be a bit off.
>
> [ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'administratoren'  Key being added: 'administratoren']
>     System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add) +7484392
>     System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(Object key, Object value) +11
>     System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection.Add(MembershipUser user) +129
>     ASPPG.MembershipProviders.ASPPGSqlMembershipProvider.CreateMembershipUserCollectionFromDataView(DataView dv) in H:\My Document\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\forumu\MembershipProviders\ASPPGSqlMembershipProvider.vb:656
>     ASPPG.MembershipProviders.ASPPGSqlMembershipProvider.GetAllUsers(Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Int32& totalRecords) in H:\My Document\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\forumu\MembershipProviders\ASPPGSqlMembershipProvider.vb:360
>     System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers(Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Int32& totalRecords) +65
>     System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers() +26
>     MemberInfo.GetAllMembers() in d:\Faelles\SVN-exports\DFF-umbraco\App_Code\MemberInfo.cs:71
>     usercontrols_GetMemberTopList.LoadTopMembers() in d:\Faelles\SVN-exports\DFF-umbraco\usercontrols\GetMemberTopList.ascx.cs:16
>     usercontrols_GetMemberTopList.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Faelles\SVN-exports\DFF-umbraco\usercontrols\GetMemberTopList.ascx.cs:11
>     System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>     System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
>     System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
>     System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618

Contents of MemberInfo.cs is here:

```
public class MemberInfo {

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string AddressPrimary { get; set; }
    public string AddressSecondary { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string HomepageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string MemberNo { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsApproved { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsNotMember { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsUpdated { get; set; }
    public Boolean HasReceivedWelcomeMail { get; set; }
    public int RandomNumber { get; set; }
    public int MemberType { get; set; }

    public MemberInfo() { 

    }

    public MemberInfo(string _username, string _id) {
        Username = _username;

        MembershipUser userRequested = Membership.GetUser(Username);

        ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(Username);

        IsApproved = userRequested.IsApproved;

        FirstName = profile.GetPropertyValue("Firstname").ToString();
        MiddleName = profile.GetPropertyValue("Middlename").ToString();
        LastName = profile.GetPropertyValue("Lastname").ToString();
        AddressPrimary = profile.GetPropertyValue("AddressPrimary").ToString();
        AddressSecondary = profile.GetPropertyValue("AddressSecondary").ToString();
        Zip = profile.GetPropertyValue("Zip").ToString();
        Country = profile.GetPropertyValue("Country").ToString();
        HomepageUrl = profile.GetPropertyValue("HomepageUrl").ToString();
        HasReceivedWelcomeMail = Boolean.Parse(profile.GetPropertyValue("WelcomeMailSent").ToString());

        if (FirstName.Length > 2) {
            string strFullName = FirstName + " " + MiddleName + " " + LastName;
            Fullname = strFullName.Replace("  ", " ");
        }
        else {
            Fullname = Username;
        }

        MemberNo = profile.GetPropertyValue("MemberNo").ToString();
        IsNotMember = Boolean.Parse(profile.GetPropertyValue("NotMember").ToString());
        Email = userRequested.Email;
        Id = _id;

        if (profile.GetPropertyValue("Description").ToString() != "") {
            IsUpdated = true;
        }
        else {

            if (umbraco.library.GetXmlNodeById("1352").Current.SelectSingleNode("node [@nodeName='" + Username + "']/node") == null) {
                IsUpdated = false;
            }
            else {
                IsUpdated = true;
            }

        }
        RandomNumber = ss.NumberStuff.GenerateRandomNumber(0, 10000000);

        MemberType = 1;

        if (IsApproved == false && HasReceivedWelcomeMail == false) { // Not yet approved
            MemberType = 1;
        }

        if (IsApproved == false && HasReceivedWelcomeMail == true) { // Deleted
            MemberType = 2;
        }

        if (IsApproved == true && IsNotMember == false) { // Members
            MemberType = 3;
        }

        if (IsApproved == true && IsNotMember == true) { // Administrators
            MemberType = 4;
        }

    }

    private static object objLock = new object();

    public List<MemberInfo> GetAllMembers() {
        return GetAllMembers(false);
    }

    public List<MemberInfo> GetAllMembers(Boolean bIncludeAdministrators) {

        MembershipUserCollection allUsers;
        lock (objLock) {
            allUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        }

        List<MemberInfo> memberInfoList = new List<MemberInfo>();

        foreach (MembershipUser userCurrent in allUsers) {
            MemberInfo mInfo = new MemberInfo(userCurrent.UserName, userCurrent.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
            if (mInfo.Id == "0") {
                continue;
            }

            if (mInfo.IsNotMember == true && bIncludeAdministrators == false) {
                continue;
            }

            memberInfoList.Add(mInfo);
        }

        return memberInfoList;

    }

    public static String GetMemberTypeName(int intMemberType) {

        switch (intMemberType) {

            case 1: {
                return "Endnu ikke godkendt";
            }

            case 2: {
                return "Slettet";
            }

            case 3: {
                return "Medlem";
            }

            case 4: {
                return "Administrator";
            }

            default: {
                return "";
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: Added new source of MemberInfo.cs and updated what error message I get.
Notice that the stack trace is still the old one, so the line numbers it is referring to can be a little off.

Edit: A lot of info about the error has been changed. New MemberInfo.cs added. Removed code from the login method as I now know that this is not the cause of the error.

Comment: Can it really be true that noone knows anything about this? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the site stores some session data in a table.
In certain cases this table would get outdated and then the site would crash.
I have added some clean up code to clean the table if an error is about to happen.

Thanks to everybody who tried to help me :)

Answer (score 3):

```
[ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'administratoren' Key being added: 'administratoren']
```

It seems you have duplicate usernames in `allUsers` (var allUsers =...) but you the variable has just defined so there is no chance to put another 'administratoren' in it and get the exception at the same line unless something is happening at the same line. Since membership doesn't allow duplicate KEYs (usernames), the problem is with casting which is happening after retreiving users at the end of your single line of code :

```
Line 71: var allUsers = from u in Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast() select u;
```

change to:

```
Line 71: var allUsers = from u in Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>() select u;
```

Also using var or writing many statements in a single line of code are not good ideas.

Comment: I have just found out that it is only if I try to log in on a specific page that the error occurs. I will try and look into it and also seperate the code a bit more instead of doing to much in one line as you point out. Hope I will get somewhere with this.. :S

Comment: Also, the code actually is like you suggest it should be (with the MembershipUser after the Cast. It have just disappeared when I pasted it here :S

Comment: The clue is, something is wrong at that line. Please let us know what happened after breaking-up that line of code. @Mark: using good practices (Collective Wisdom) is not about working or not working code. As we see EmKay's trouble with a ... code by somebody else, you can continue using var but you don't know when you get the bill. var is useful when you don't care about the result or the type is not recognized until run-time.

Comment: I have not broken up the line and I am still receiving the same error. I have added the new source and the new error as written in my edit comment.

Comment: BTW.. I have also found out that it is not the built in Membership provider that is used. It is a special one used with ASPPlayground, so I will also ask them if they know what the error could be.

Comment: Being pessimist, I'll think of a hard-coded administrator account somewhere, but don't talk about it unless you have carefully investigate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I read your problem . I have not much experience of working in website application. 
One thing is that "Hash Table" can contain only unique values. when you are trying to enter same key and if it is already there in Hash table, it will give you an error.

So, I would suggest you to use your Authentication method. when we are using Microsoft's provided functionality , we can not have a control over them . so better use your own Authentication and control them.

Comment: Exactly.. I couldn't agree with you more. Normally I don't use the built-in Authentication methods, but unfortunately this is not possible in this case as it is a project that was transferred to me after someone else started it. :( The website is quite large now, so changing the whole login procedure and authentication is not an option. I just want to fix the bug in the implementation of the built-in method. I can't imagine that the bug is in the built-in method...

Comment: yes...i am not saying that there is bug in built-in method. i am saying that we can't have a good control on those methods. and i understand your situation. unfortunately i can't help as i don't have knowledge of that.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't being caused by the login code. It looks like it is a bug in the MemberInfo.cs file.  This code is being called from the GetMemberTopList user control.  If you post that code we may be able to help more but I suggest attaching a debugger and looking at the stack when the exception is thrown.

Comment: I will try with the debugger next time it presents itself.. It's just not very easy the way this project is set up :(

Comment: Last time I thought passing the parameter to function forces it to add an administrator in system. Now without it you get the same error. A pessimistic guess: Maybe the library is replace by a hacker which is trying to add a default administrator to system. But I still think this is a race condition. Remember the inner object (HashTable) is static and you should put the lock over it not your code.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should override equality and hash operation for your entity. For example by Id.

Answer (score 0):

@EDIT:

Remove `static` from the following line, or call the function without `bIncludeAdministrators`:

```
Line 108: public static List GetAllMembers(Boolean bIncludeAdministrators)
```

**Reason:** Each request in ASP.NET is served by a different thread from ASP.NET thread pool, if two thread reaches this line simultaneously, then `GetAllMembers()` is called from two different threads at the same time. It seems this method is not implemented thread-safe and doesn't provide a lock over `HashTable` while it's adding items to it. Then latter thread would try to add the same key to `HashTable`.

Comment: I have now tried your solution. Did not work :( I also looked a bit into the issue about thread safety and put in a lock. Did not work either. Updated source with both corrections have been added above.